# Find key by its index number in an object list and replace with new user input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

Have an object like

```
{
  A: { lists: 2, name: 'John' },
  B: { lists: 2, name: 'Tom' },
  C: { lists: 1, name: 'Harry' }
}
```

Here what I want to achieve is select the object key based on its index in the list of object and replace that key with a new input value.

Lets say index id 1 and new key value is T then the key B will be replaced with T and the new object will return as

```
{
  A: { lists: 2, name: 'John' },
  T: { lists: 2, name: 'Tom' },
  C: { lists: 1, name: 'Harry' }
}
```

Any help would be great. I have gone through other questions but the answers are not helpful for me.

Comment: Objects do not have proper guaranteed order, index 1 ( i.e key B) might be the key C when you access it the next time

Comment: Index id?  The position of properties in objects isn't cross-platform reliable, so today index 2 might be tomorrow's index 4.  You should use an array if you need to keep things in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method. Get key-value pairs array using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method. Then traverse the array using reduce and change the required key. At last, return the resultant object.

```js
const change = (array, index, key) => {
  return Object.entries(array).reduce((prev, [x, y], i) => {
    const p = prev;
    if (i === index) p[key] = { ...y };
    else p[x] = { ...y };
    return p;
  }, {});
};
const data = {
  A: { lists: 2, name: 'John' },
  B: { lists: 2, name: 'Tom' },
  C: { lists: 1, name: 'Harry' },
};
const ret = change(data, 1, 'T');
console.log(ret);
```